# IKE の Phase 2 の ID とは?

Tags: network, vpn

YAMAHA の IPsec の設定画面を見ていました。そこで、 IPsec の設定を行なうローカルとリモートの設定として、 IKE の ID の設定方法が記載されていました。

参考:
http://www.rtpro.yamaha.co.jp/RT/docs/ipsec/command.html#ipsec.ike.local.id

## 質問

これは、ちょっと調べると、 IKE の Phase 2 で利用される ID であるようだ、と思っていますが、この ID は、 IKE においてどのように利用されるのでしょうか?

つまり、ここはとりあえずリモートとローカルで同じ設定ができれば良いものなのか、それとも、この設定は IP/mask のような設定値であるので、何かしらの実際の通信方法を規定するパラメータであるのか、といったことが分かっていないです。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IPSec (というより IKEv1) は、その仕様としてフェーズ1で作成した ISAKMP SA を利用して、複数の IPSec SA を定義できるようになっている様子です。なので、一つの ISAKMP SA の中で、どのような通信たちについての IPSec を張りたいのか、を相手側に伝える必要があり、それを ID (これは、 ISAKMP の Identification ペイロードに対応する) で伝えている様子です。

自分が把握しているかぎりでは、少くとも YAMAHA の RTX では、 ID は純粋に ID として利用されていて、リモートとローカルで想定するそれぞれの ID を一致させておけば、ひとまず問題なさそうだ、と思っています。

(さらにいうと、 yamaha では一つの ISAKMP SA に対しては、高々1つのペア(行・帰)の IPSec SA しか張らないので、あまり気にする必要はなさそうだ、とも思っています)